# Need to set controls anchor property

Tags: c#, winforms

One of my windows constitutes many controls, I need to set anchor property **top and right** ,Note: I need to handle positional property independently for each control. I don't want to set this property manually .Need help to set anchor property for the control dynamically.

I write the bellow syntax

```
 DynamicControlsProperty od = new DynamicControlsProperty();
    foreach (Control item in this.controls)
    {
        item.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        item.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right);
    }
```

Using the above syntax on my window form, controls are not appear as anchor set on the above syntax.Controls are appear as **default** anchor set.

Comment: What is `DynamicControlsProperty`?

Comment: Im not understandig that are you doing. But the code above should work correctly. So its likely that error in another piece of your code

Comment: What you mean by "Controls are appear as default anchor set"? How can you tell? Also, do you have `Dock` set as well? Because you can have either Anchor or Dock, not both.

Answer (score 33):

Try to use this

```
 foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
 {
      item.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write the code to set `Anchor` property programmatically only in the `Form_Load` event of the form. If you write that code anywhere else, e.g. on `button_click`, then you would have to write the following line after it:

```
this.Invalidate(true);
```

However, this may lead to unexpected results if your form is already in the maximized mode.

Comment: Actually, the best place to write that code is in the *constructor*.

Comment: Right, in the constructor you allocate and setup the objects but everything related to the disposition have to be written into the Load method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to set the location.  I liked Stecya's solutoin, but it didn't work for me.

```
MyControl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```